# Safari: "JavaScript error detected! Error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object"

Tags: macos, safari, error, javascript

Whenever I connect to a WiFi at Starbucks, I'm prompted with this warning:

[image]

After clicking **OK** everything is fine and I can login as usual.

- What's causing this error?
- How do I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely their problem. Their JavaScript programmer didn't do a good job in handling stuff.

Comment: Could you please extend your answer a bit more? Like: Why is this a problem of the website and not a bug of the browser? Thanks :)

Comment: From the error, it seems like the JavaScript is expecting a certain type of object, but when the JavaScript is running in your browser, the object isn't generated, and a null object is returned to the JavaScript. The JavaScript doesn't know how to handle this null object and therefore an error is thrown.

Comment: This is a good and comprehensable explanation!

Comment: what this usually is, is a common scripting issue with page load and page init events in different browsers. Coupled with the relative execution speeds of JS in newer browsers whereby the script that throws the "null" error is expecting the initialisation code to already have been run, when in fact it has not.  Basically, older code on BTOpenzone's part.  Most client-side developers now use jQuery (or it's ilk) which has much better page events synchronisation than using the built in page events of the browsers in use.